# Data Grid with native Android scroller gets stuck or does not show the whole list

Tags: livecode

I'm using the Data Grid with native Android scroller with the code below.
When using it for just one view in the Data Grid it works OK. But when switching between different views the scrolling of the DG does not work anymore - it gets stuck or does not show the whole list - see the complete description in the document with screenshots [here](http://www.divshare.com/download/26783229-58d)
See also the [stack](http://www.divshare.com/download/26783228-f09).

What do I have to change in the code and where to make it work properly?

```
   local sScrollerID,isScrolling

on openCard
   ## Create scroller now:
   create_scroller
   pass openCard -- added just to see if it helps; it does not
end openCard

on closecard
   delete_scroller
   pass closeCard -- added just to see if it helps; it does not
end closecard

command create_scroller   
   put "DataGrid 1" into tScrollerGroup

   if the environment <> "mobile" then
      exit create_scroller
   end if

   ## Create native scroller object and save its ID in a local variable
   MobileControlCreate "scroller"
   put the result into sScrollerID

   ## RECT is the area on the card where the SCOLLER should do its work
   MobileControlSet sScrollerID, "rect", (the rect of grp tScrollerGroup)

   put the width of grp tScrollerGroup into tWidth
   put the dgFormattedheight of grp tScrollerGroup into tHeight
   set the dgvScroll of grp tScrollerGroup to 0

   ## WHAT part fo the datagrid shall be scrolled-> the complete datagrid
   MobileControlSet sScrollerID, "contentRect", (0,0,tWidth,tHeight)

   ## Display SCROLLER
   MobileControlSet sScrollerID, "visible", "true"

   ## the typical BUMP effect when you ge to the edge of the object
   MobileControlSet sScrollerID, "canBounce", "true"
   MobileControlSet sScrollerID, "pagingEnabled", "false"

   MobileControlSet sScrollerID, "vIndicator", "false"
   MobileControlSet sScrollerID,  "borderStyle", "none"

   MobileControlSet sScrollerID, "canScrollToTop", "false"
end create_scroller

## Will be sent when the user actually SCROLLs with his finger
on scrollerDidScroll OffsetX, OffsetY
   lock screen
   put true into isScrolling
   set the dgvScroll of grp "DataGrid 1" to OffsetY
   unlock screen
end scrollerDidScroll

## REMOVE natove object when card closes!!!!!
command delete_scroller
   if the environment <> "mobile" then
      exit delete_scroller
   end if
   MobileControlDelete sScrollerID   
end delete_scroller
```

---

I tried to solve it by changing the local variables to global ones. Then I put empty into global ones in every button that has script for opening different view in the data grid but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

I added this line: `send "delete_scroller" to cd "main" in 0 sec` in each handler (at the beginning of it) that creates new view in the data grid
and this one: `send "create_scroller" to cd "main" in 0 sec` in the same handler at the end of it.
In other words, I had to delete and create the scroller each time the data grid was updated with new data.